# Converge in Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with standard
Cauchy distribution, on the same probability space, and let $M_n = \max(X_1,...,X_n)$. Prove that $(nM^{-1}_n)_{n\ge1}$ converges in distribution and identify the limit.

ga

Comment: Did you try to compute the distribution for a given $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a homework problem, I will provide some hints.

- First, we can try to determine the limit in law of $\frac{M_n}n$. So a natural idea is to compute the limit $F_n(t):=P(M_n\leqslant nt)$ for a fixed $t$.
- We find that $F_n(0)=2^{-n}$, hence we can consider $t>0$.
- The relationship $\arctan s+\arctan(s^{-1})=\frac{\pi}2$ for $s$ positive gives that $F_n(t)=\left(1-\frac 1{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac 1{nt}\right)\right)^n$ for such $t$.
- The limit to $0$ is deterministic, and can we computed by calculus tools.

Comment: The limit to $0$ is $1$, correct?

Comment: No, since the logarithm of this expression behaves as $-\frac 1{\pi t}$.

Comment: Still confused with this one, when you say in the last line that "the limit to $0$ is deterministic", what limit are you referring to?

Comment: Did you mean determine the limit in law of $\frac{n}{M_{n}}$?

Comment: @Chris I suggest to determine the law of the inverse, which is $\frac{M_n}n$. By deterministic, I mean "non random".

Comment: Thanks, I will post my answer in a few days, but the hints were great.